# TypeError using getter and setter in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, get, set, typeerror

I am using getter and setter to set a field from the web cache, but I get the `TypeError` when I try to use the setter for example. The error is:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.saveCache is not a function
```

The getter and setter are below:

```
    get saveCache (): any {
        if (localStorage.getItem('saveCache') === null) {
          return null;
        }
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saveCache'));
      }
      
      set saveCache(value:any) {
        localStorage.setItem('saveCache', JSON.stringify(value));
      }
```

When I try to set the `saveCache` field, I get the above error. How can I solve this issue?

I added an example here with the error:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cryfvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
```

Comment: you defined setter and getter. it is expected that you use them like this: `var cache = something.saveCache` or `something.saveCache = newValue`. if you want to use these things as methods then remove `get` and `set` keyword

Answer (score 1):

A setter has to be used as below:

```js
this.saveCache = this.fruits;
```

and not `this.saveCache(this.fruits);`